# Why doesn't `go env` command reflect change in environment variable?

Tags: go, delve, goinstall

In my system, `GOBIN` variable was unset (empty value). Now unlike some other GO env variables, this seems unset even in the output for `go env` command. (I'm user `ubuntu`, so `~` is `/home/ubuntu/`)

```
echo $GOBIN
   //empty
echo $GOPATH
   //empty
echo $GOROOT
   //empty
go env GOBIN
   //empty
go env GOPATH
/home/ubuntu/go
go env GOROOT
/usr/local/go
which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

1. Why does `go env` give values different from the system environment variables? I couldn't find any documentation on this, but my assumption is that if env variables are not set at the system level, Golang sets default values - which are shown by `go env`. Is this assumption correct?
2. Why is `GOBIN` unset? I tried setting the system env variable explicitly, but it doesn't get reflected in `go env`, even though the system env variable seems to get modified. Why is that so?

```
echo $GOBIN
     //empty
go env GOBIN
     //empty
go env GOPATH
/home/ubuntu/go
GOBIN=‘/home/ubuntu/go/bin’
echo $GOBIN
/home/ubuntu/go/bin
go env GOBIN
     //empty
```

The official documentation (https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go) says:

> Env prints Go environment information

but it doesn't mention where the said variables are sourced from.

---

Problem X (https://xyproblem.info/)

I am trying to install Delve (https://github.com/go-delve/delve), and my system has two go versions (`go1.10.1` and `go1.17.8`), and I plan to use the latter (unfortunately can't remove the former)

`go1.17.8 go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest` makes a new directory at `/home/ubuntu` => `go` and adds Delve here. But `dlv version` is unrecognized.
From `go help env`, `GOBIN` is where `go install` should install binaries - in my case it's unset, so I'm guessing Golang installs it at `GOPATH`. But even then, I expected the binary to be recognized.  I also tried adding the location to my `PATH`, but that didn't work either.

3. Should I set my GOBIN to anything specific before installation via `go1.17.8`?
4. Is my system having 2 go versions (`which go` is pointing to the go1.10.1 version), causing this? (1.10.1 doesn't have Modules support, but I was trying the install via go.17.8, so I assumed this wouldn't be an issue)

Comment: @volker Thanks for the feedback, removed images,  posted cmd and results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These go env variables are variables set at the time of installation your binary.

Please refer the code of https://github.com/golang:

- as per https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/internal/buildcfg/cfg.go,
  these variables are either taken from environment variables or default variables.
- These default values are generated as per runtime https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/dist/buildruntime.go#L48

Thus, these variables do not appear as part of Operating systems environment variables.

These variables can be overridden by config file at  os.UserConfigDir or by command `go env NAME=VALUE`.

Answer (score 3):

go on Linux will store persistent settings to this file:

```
$HOME/.config/go/env
```

via the `go env -w` command. Since the go tool loads settings from ***both*** this config ***and*** ENV VARS - this explains why you may see differing values. The go tool combines both.